# Auto-adapt width on output file

Tags: pdf, output

How can I make sure that in the output .pdf file the layout width is adapted automatically, without having to do it manually? Here is what my document looks like when it is opened [image]

I know I should paste the source code, but since there are about 700 lines, I report only about the geometry package

```
    \usepackage[a4paper,
                bindingoffset=0.2in,
                left=1in,
                right=1in,
                top=1in,
                bottom=1in,
                footskip=.25in]
   {geometry}
```

[Full code here](https://pastebin.com/ufFvwDKn)

Comment: What do you mean by “layout width”?

Comment: Do you know Adobe Reader? In the toolbar there is a drop-down menu that allows you to choose the zoom. Here, I would like to make sure that .pdf file, when opened, is displayed at the width that fits the screen

Comment: Add the `pdfstartview=FitH` option to `hyperref`.